# Refreshing data in a webcomponent from Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, web-component

UPDATE: I found that what I was looking for is Firebase's .onSnapshot function, as in:

```
db.collection("prjects")
    .onSnapshot(function(data) {}
```

My current problem is that I cannot pass a reference into .onSnapshot(). Here's what I mean:

```
import Template from "./template.js";
import { db } from "../../util/firebase.js";

export default class Dashboard extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });

        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = Template.render();
        this.dom = Template.mapDOM(this.shadowRoot);

        if (this.dom.projectList) {
            console.log("this.dom.projectList is defined")
        } // checking if this.dom.projectList is defined: it is!

        db.collection("projects")
            .onSnapshot(function (data) {
                var html = "";
                data.forEach(function (doc) {
                    const project = doc.data();
                    const li = `
                        <li>
                            <h5>${project.title}</h5>
                            <p>${project.description}</p>
                        </li>
                    `;
                    html += li;
                    console.log("test", html);
                });

                this.dom.projectList.innerHTML = html;  // not defined!!

            }, error => { console.log("Oops! ", error) });
    }
```

I still can't refresh the page content... How can I get access to "this.dom.projectList" inside .onSnpashot() ?

=======================================================================

I am  developping a webcomponent that lists projects stored in a Firebase Firestore database and I want it to auto-refresh when the someone adds another project in Firestore.

My problem is with the second part (refreshing). My understanding of webcomponents life-cycle is that potential useful states are: constructor (component is loaded in memory, happen once), the connectedCallback (component displayed), attributeChangedCallback (attribute has changed, state changed). This last one might be interesting but passing tens of attrbutes in an element, sounds strange to me: firebase's "snapshot.docs" can contain a lot of data to deserialize.

I am trying to see new content without reloading the whole page.

How do you solve this problem?

Here is my current web-component code:

```
import Template from "./template.js";
import {db} from "../../util/firebase.js";

export default class Dashboard extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.attachShadow({mode:"open"});

        db.collection("projects").get().then(snapshot => {
            this.setupProjects(snapshot.docs);
            const data = snapshot.docs;
            data.forEach(doc => {
                console.log(doc.data().title)
            })
        }); 
    
    


        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = Template.render();
        this.dom = Template.mapDOM(this.shadowRoot);
    }

    setupProjects(data) {
        let html = "";
        data.forEach(doc => {
            const project = doc.data();
            const li = `
                <li>
                    <h5>${project.title}</h5>
                    <p>${project.description}</p>
                </li>
            `;
            html += li;
        })

        this.dom.projectList.innerHTML = html;
    }
};

if (!customElements.get("dashboard-page")){
    customElements.define("dashboard-page", Dashboard);
}
```

And this is how my template is built:

````
export default {
    render() {
        return `
        ${this.html()}
        ${this.css()}`
    },
    mapDOM(scope){
        return {
            projectList: scope.querySelector("#projectList")
        }
    },
    html() {
        return `
            Welcome Home, logged in.
            <ul id="projectList"></ul>
            `
    },
    css(){
        return`
        <style>
        </style>`
    }
}

```

Any idea will be welcome because I have none...

Thank you!
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, my understanding is that it was a scope issue. I added:

```
let that = this;
```

before:

```
 db.collection("projects").get().then(snapshot => {
        that.setupProjects(snapshot.docs);  // notice the "that", not this.
        const data = snapshot.docs;
        data.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc.data().title)
        })
    }
 );
```

Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

- Make your Component listen for an Event

  ```
    document.addEventListener("NewData",(evt=>{
      let newdata = evt.detail;
    })
  ```
- Dispatch a Custom Event when the data changes

  ```
  document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('NewData', {
     detail: YOUR DATA HERE,
  }));
  ```
- https://open-wc.org/faq/events.html
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: Thank you. I think there's something native from Firebase I can use. I am trying: db.collection("projects").onSnapshot(function(data){...}).then(function(data){...}) ... but keeps gettings errors (.then not a function).

Comment: then ``db.collection("projects").onSnapshot(function(data){...})`` does not return a Promise

Comment: yeah... I learnt it was an synchronious function... So I wrote the function I want to call inside of onSnapshot(). However for one reason or another, I can't reference a variable outside (this.dom.projectList). I updated the first post (top of the page), maybe you could have a look, it may be obvious for you. Anyway, thank you for your time.